# Take a Screenshot Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot using kotlin, but i am creating layout alements dinamically by code.
When i try to take a screenshot using `view.draw(canvas)` or `view.drawToBitmap()` method the btimap is empty.

I must to take a screensoht for entire screen; And the screen elements change after a time dinamically.

Comment: What API version are you targetting? For 24 and up, you are lucky: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy

Comment: minSdkVersion 22

Comment: The same, `PixelCopy.request` returns a empty Bitmap :(